# .NET Core 2.0 Adding a new field to ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, database-schema

I have a .NET Core 2.0 MVC project. I initially added 4 fields to the ApplicationUser - then in Nuget Package Manager Console, I ran Add-Migration Initial. I have added a number of users to the database, and now I need to add another field to that Model. I added the boolean field "Deactivated" in the ApplicationUser model, I updated the ApplicationUsersController to add the new field to the Bind methods

```
Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Name,DateCreated,DateUpdated,LastLogin,Id,UserName,NormalizedUserName,Email,NormalizedEmail,EmailConfirmed,PasswordHash,SecurityStamp,ConcurrencyStamp,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumberConfirmed,TwoFactorEnabled,LockoutEnd,LockoutEnabled,AccessFailedCount,Deactivated")] ApplicationUser applicationUser)
```

Then I ran Add-Migration UserTableUpdate and Update-Database

I get the error

> Application startup exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Invalid column name 'Deactivated'.) ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Deactivated'.

I tried adding the column to the DB manually but then it tries to re-add the column as a duplicate and throws an error saying it cant add a column with the same name. Where did I go wrong?

**ApplicationDBContext.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TestProject.Models;

namespace TestProject.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }

        public DbSet<TestProject.Models.CustomErrorLogModel> CustomErrorLogModel { get; set; }

        public DbSet<TestProject.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**UserTableUpdate** migration

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestProject.Data.Migrations
{
    public partial class UserTableUpdate : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<bool>(
                name: "Deactivated",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                nullable: true,
                defaultValue: false);
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "Deactivated",
                table: "AspNetUsers");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, insert the code of your ApplicationDbContext.

Comment: When you say that you added the column "manually", do you mean using an EF migration command line?

Comment: No, I tried adding it to the database from within SQL Server management studio.

Comment: You should try applying it using the EF command line [EF Command Line Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet). It sounds like your app is trying to apply the migration because it doesn't know that you have done it manually (i.e. the migration history table has not been updated).

Comment: Also, with your initial `Invalid column name 'Deactivated'`. It sounds like your app is trying to access the user table before the migration has been applied (hence the error when trying to retrieve the `Deactivated` column).

Comment: @user6383418 Could you share us your test project to reproduce your issue? I followed your steps and code, it works correctly.